# Dependency library unable to access relative node modules imports

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I need to add a UI toolkit dependency in my project. The dependency injects two libraries in node-modules

```
—toolkit
 —toolkit-core
 —toolkit-ui
```

I need to use files from toolkit-ui. But the toolkit-ui is importing relative dependency as below:

```
@import "toolkit-core/tools"
```

When the project compiles it gives me below error :

```
ERROR in ./css/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--5-2!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./css/app.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

@import "toolkit-core/tools";
^
  File to import not found or unreadable: toolkit-core/tools.
```

My webpack set up as below

```
const { resolve, join} = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postCssLoader = {
  loader: 'postcss-loader',
  options: {
    plugins: function() {
      return [autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie 10'] })];
    }
  }
};
module.exports = (projectDir) => [
…
  {
    test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
    use: [
    'style-loader', 'css-loader', postCssLoader, 'resolve-url-loader', 
     {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true,
              includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
            }
          }
    ]
  },
…
]
```

Can someone please suggest how can I resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved above.

I was importing webpack loaders from a common build directory. I was trying to override it by adding a new rule for `scss|css`. But that didn't seem to work. Webpack used the first rule for `scss|css` loaders.

However if I replace that rule by my in app rule. It works.